# Ternary Operators and Text Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, react-native-elements

I am creating an app that is text to sound translator. And I am using input text from react-native-elements, as well as ternary operators. How do I check if the text input box is empty or has any special characters? The app is supposed to detect this and send an alert.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: And why is this related to "ternary operator" ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show alert when text input is empty and detect special character and show alert, as well as remove the added special character from input

```
const [inputVal,setInputValue] = React.useState('')
return (


<Input
  value={inputVal}
  placeholder="Comment"
  
  onChangeText={value => {

     if(value==''){
      alert('Text Input Empty')
    }

     let format = /[!"`'#%&,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+/


     if(format.test(value)){
      alert('Special Character Entered')
      let rmvalue = value.slice(0,-1)
       setInputValue(rmvalue)
    }else setInputValue(value)

     
  }}
  />
 );
```